# while embedding media with ckeditor it shows permission asking box

Tags: embed, media, ckeditor4.x

i am using ckeditor4 in my project. For embedding instagram feeds i have used embed plugin with ckeditor. but that plugin first time asking visitors a permission alert for showing the media
[image]

how can i remove that?? I have to show media directly and not able to say every customer to click that button.

I have to show media directly and not able to say every customer to click that button.

Answer (score 0):

just try to update your cfg for embed provider, add `consent=0`

```
embed_provider: '//ckeditor.iframe.ly/api/oembed?url={url}&callback={callback}&consent=0',
```